# "Shape Mode" for ControlP5

Tags: processing, control-p5

Vanilla Processing has [`shapeMode()`](https://processing.org/reference/shapeMode_.html) for modifying "the location from which shapes draw." How, if possible, can one get the same functionality drawing UI "controllers" with [ControlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/)?

Concretely, I have tried the following code:

```java
shapeMode(CENTER);
cp5.addButton("On/Off")
.setPosition(width/2, height/2)
.setSize(300, 300)
.setColorBackground(color(0, 113, 0));
```

And got this result:

[image: Screenshot]

But what I would like to see is this:

[image]

Obviously something like `.setPosition(width/2 - buttonWidth/2, height/2 - buttonWidth/2)` would work, but I would like to keep the code minimal.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the `shapeMode()` function only changes the mode of shapes drawn with the `shape()` function.

ControlP5 doesn't use the `shape()` function to draw buttons. It uses the `rect()` function.

You can use the `rectMode()` function to change how rectangles are drawn. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/rectMode_.html).

But I doubt you'll be pleased with the results. That will move the rectangle of the button, but it won't move the text of the buttons, so all of your text will be off-center. That's just one issue, I'm sure there will be plenty of others.

If I were you I would just do the calculations myself. If you're really worried about keeping your code minimal, then you could create your own wrapper classes or utility functions that encapsulate the "logic" required to do the offsetting. But imho you should be more worried about keeping your code readable and maintainable.